# Error when binding and unbinding keystrokes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion

I was just adding features to my notepad in Tkinter when this happened. I added a bulleted list button which functions just like any other bulleted list you would see in a notepad. This is my code for the bulleted list:

```
def bulletList():
    bullet = "  •  "

    global bulleted
    if bulleted == True:
        bulleted = False
        entry.unbind("<Return>",bulletList())
    elif bulleted == False:
        bulleted = True
        entry.insert(END,f"{bullet}")
        entry.bind("<Return>",bulletList())
```

For context, `bulleted` is set to `False` by default, when the button is not clicked yet. But when it is, I call this function. Apparently though, there was a bug in this function, making it loop infinitely and resulting in a max recursion depth error. Sorry I couldn't attach the error, but it just alternates between the bind and unbind function until the max recursion depth is met.

Hopefully a solution to this error can be found! Again, I am a beginner to TKinter, so I don't know how to solve this even if it might be common. Thanks!

Comment: Try not calling the function with `()`: `entry.unbind("<Return>",bulletList)`

Comment: @CoolCloud It will only display one bullet, and if you press Enter after that it will raise an error:

TypeError: bulletList() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

Comment: Then make it `def bulletList(e):`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work at all.

Comment: Then give an example we can run and try

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432